# Tomcat 7 connect to remote MySQL host

Tags: mysql, tomcat

I am trying to connect Tomcat 7.0.54 to a remote MySQL host - I have enabled remote access on the remote MySQL server and I can ping the remote MySQL server and can connect and list tables etc remotely from the Tomcat host.

When I try and connect in Tomcat application I get an error:

> Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the
>   server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets
>   from the server.

and then further down in the dump I get:

> Inner error: Message:  Connection refused

I am a complete newbie to Tomcat so I am struggling to know where to go with this - I can connect to MySQL so it doesn't seem to be the remote MySQL server or networking which means something in Tomcat or the Java app is causing the problem. There is nothing in the Tomcat log files nor the application itself pointing to an issue - what else can I try?

Trace dump:

> Inner error: Message:  Communications link failure  The last packet
>   sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has
>   not received any packets from the server. Source:  Stack Trace:   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:355)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2461) 
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:822)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
>   at
>   Mainsoft.Data.Jdbc.Providers.GenericProvider$JdbcUrlConnector.get_Connection(GenericProvider.cs:183)
>   at
>   Mainsoft.Data.Jdbc.Providers.GenericProvider.GetConnection(GenericProvider.cs:336)
>   at
>   system.Data.ProviderBase.AbstractDBConnection.Open(AbstractDBConnection.cs:495)
>   at rdServer.rdSqlReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.rdDb.access$4300(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.rdDb.CreateDataReader(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.rdDb.ProcessData(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.rdDb.ProcessDataLayerElement(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.rdDb.xmlGetData(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.rdDb9.xmlGetData(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.rdAnalysisGrid10.ResetData(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.rdAnalysisGrid10.BuildAnalysisGrid(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcess_AnalysisGrid(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)
>   at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcess_Body(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)
>   at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcess_Report(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.PageBuilder.BuildHtml(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.ResponseBuilder.BuildResponse(Unknown Source)  at
>   ASP.rdpage_aspx.__Render__control1(rdPage.aspx:4)  at
>   ASP.rdpage_aspx$__Impl0.Invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   system.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(Control.cs:1101)  at
>   system.Web.UI.Control.Render(Control.cs:1090)  at
>   system.Web.UI.Page.Render(Page.cs:1095)  at
>   system.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(Control.cs:1254)  at
>   system.Web.UI.Page.RenderPage(Page.cs:1621)  at
>   system.Web.UI.Page.encodeChildren(Page.jvm.cs:159)  at
>   Mainsoft.Web.Hosting.BaseFacesViewHandler.renderView(BaseFacesViewHandler.cs:58)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:132)
>   at
>   Mainsoft.Web.Hosting.ServletFacesPageHandler.ProcessRequest(ServletFacesPageHandler.cs:116)
>   at
>   Mainsoft.Web.Hosting.SessionWrapper$SessionWrapperHandler.ProcessRequest(SessionWrapper.cs:40)
>   at
>   system.Web.HttpApplication$Pipelined__7.MoveNext$Z$$*$Pipeline$*$d__7$$(HttpApplication.cs:1033)
>   at system.Web.HttpApplication.Tick(HttpApplication.cs:705)  at
>   system.Web.HttpApplication.Start(HttpApplication.cs:1217)  at
>   system.Web.HttpApplication.System_Web_IHttpAsyncHandler_BeginProcessRequest(HttpApplication.cs:1319)
>   at system.Web.HttpRuntime.RealProcessRequest(HttpRuntime.cs:482)  at
>   system.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(HttpRuntime.cs:523)  at
>   Mainsoft.Web.Hosting.BaseHttpServlet.service(BaseHttpServlet.cs:200) 
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Inner error: Message:  Connection refused Source:  Stack Trace:   at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)  at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)  at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:425)  at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:241)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:305)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2461) 
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:822)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
>   at
>   Mainsoft.Data.Jdbc.Providers.GenericProvider$JdbcUrlConnector.get_Connection(GenericProvider.cs:183)
>   at
>   Mainsoft.Data.Jdbc.Providers.GenericProvider.GetConnection(GenericProvider.cs:336)
>   at
>   system.Data.ProviderBase.AbstractDBConnection.Open(AbstractDBConnection.cs:495)
>   at rdServer.rdSqlReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.rdDb.access$4300(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.rdDb.CreateDataReader(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.rdDb.ProcessData(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.rdDb.ProcessDataLayerElement(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.rdDb.xmlGetData(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.rdDb9.xmlGetData(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.rdAnalysisGrid10.ResetData(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.rdAnalysisGrid10.BuildAnalysisGrid(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcess_AnalysisGrid(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)
>   at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcess_Body(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElementChildren(Unknown Source)
>   at rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcess_Report(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.PageBuilder.sProcessDefinitionElement(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.PageBuilder.BuildHtml(Unknown Source)  at
>   rdServer.ResponseBuilder.BuildResponse(Unknown Source)  at
>   ASP.rdpage_aspx.__Render__control1(rdPage.aspx:4)  at
>   ASP.rdpage_aspx$__Impl0.Invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   system.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(Control.cs:1101)  at
>   system.Web.UI.Control.Render(Control.cs:1090)  at
>   system.Web.UI.Page.Render(Page.cs:1095)  at
>   system.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(Control.cs:1254)  at
>   system.Web.UI.Page.RenderPage(Page.cs:1621)  at
>   system.Web.UI.Page.encodeChildren(Page.jvm.cs:159)  at
>   Mainsoft.Web.Hosting.BaseFacesViewHandler.renderView(BaseFacesViewHandler.cs:58)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:132)
>   at
>   Mainsoft.Web.Hosting.ServletFacesPageHandler.ProcessRequest(ServletFacesPageHandler.cs:116)
>   at
>   Mainsoft.Web.Hosting.SessionWrapper$SessionWrapperHandler.ProcessRequest(SessionWrapper.cs:40)
>   at
>   system.Web.HttpApplication$Pipelined__7.MoveNext$Z$$*$Pipeline$*$d__7$$(HttpApplication.cs:1033)
>   at system.Web.HttpApplication.Tick(HttpApplication.cs:705)  at
>   system.Web.HttpApplication.Start(HttpApplication.cs:1217)  at
>   system.Web.HttpApplication.System_Web_IHttpAsyncHandler_BeginProcessRequest(HttpApplication.cs:1319)
>   at system.Web.HttpRuntime.RealProcessRequest(HttpRuntime.cs:482)  at
>   system.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(HttpRuntime.cs:523)  at
>   Mainsoft.Web.Hosting.BaseHttpServlet.service(BaseHttpServlet.cs:200) 
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: could you please show your connection code

Comment: Some solutions to try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10772407/1464763